Postgresql deleting inserted rows when deleting and inserting rows using CTE's
I want to delete all the rows on a table with a job_id of 214. Then I want to insert other records back into job_id 214. I think the delete is deleting the rows that I just got done inserting. I thought this would work from this, the last answer. When I comment out line 1, un-comment line 2 and comment the 2nd to last row, the one with the insert, I get the data output I am looking for. I just need it to insert that data output, but it does not seem to be inserting or else is being deleted right away.
WITH cte_delete AS(DELETE FROM fdw_ca_millingdb.job_detail WHERE job_id = 214),
--WITH 
newRows AS (
WITH abcT AS 
(SELECT fdw_ca_millingdb.item_abc_map.item_id AS item_id, SUM(ordered_quantity) AS ordered_quantity FROM work_order_dadsfetail
LEFT JOIN fdw_ca_millingdb.item_abc_map ON fdw_ca_millingdb.item_abc_map.abc_item_id = work_order_detail.item_id
WHERE work_order_detail.item_id ILIKE ANY (array['1%', '2%', '3%', '4%']) AND work_order_detail.id = 254919
GROUP BY fdw_ca_millingdb.item_abc_map.item_id),

logT AS
(SELECT fdw_ca_millingdb.batcher_log.item_id batcher_log_item_id, SUM(fdw_ca_millingdb.batcher_log.ending_weight - fdw_ca_millingdb.batcher_log.starting_weight) AS actual_weight FROM fdw_ca_millingdb.job
LEFT JOIN fdw_ca_millingdb.batcher_log ON fdw_ca_millingdb.batcher_log.job_id = fdw_ca_millingdb.job.id
WHERE fdw_ca_millingdb.job.work_order_id = 254919
GROUP BY fdw_ca_millingdb.batcher_log.item_id)

SELECT 214 AS job_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY abcT.item_id) - 1 AS line_num, ordered_quantity - actual_weight AS ordered_quantity,
abcT.item_id AS item_id, fdw_ca_millingdb.item.description AS item_description, bin.id AS bin_id FROM abcT
FULL JOIN logT ON logT.batcher_log_item_id = abcT.item_id
LEFT JOIN fdw_ca_millingdb.item ON fdw_ca_millingdb.item.id = abcT.item_id
LEFT JOIN fdw_ca_millingdb.bin ON fdw_ca_millingdb.bin.item_id = abcT.item_id WHERE bin.mode = 1)

INSERT INTO fdw_ca_millingdb.job_detail (job_id, line_num, ordered_quantity, item_id, item_description, bin_id)
SELECT job_id, line_num, ordered_quantity, item_id, item_description, bin_id FROM newRows;




I am not seeing any ; to execute the statement(s). 2) I am not seeing how SELECT 214 AS job_id ... and INSERT INTO fdw_ca_millingdb.job_detail ... can both happen. There can only be one query outside the  CTE((... AS ...) statements. 3) Read Data-Modifying Statements in WITH.


@AdrianKlaver I was just running this in PgAdmin at his point so I failed to put in the ;. The SELECT 214 AS job_id ... is part of the newRows cte.

From the link: The sub-statements in WITH are executed concurrently with each other and with the main query. Therefore, when using data-modifying statements in WITH, the order in which the specified updates actually happen is unpredictable. All the statements are executed with the same snapshot (see Chapter 13), so they cannot “see” one another's effects on the target tables. This alleviates the effects of the unpredictability of the actual order of row updates, and means that RETURNING data is the only way to communicate changes between different WITH sub-statements and the main query.

What do you want to execute a delete and an insert statement in 1 single query for? Why not, more simply, start a transaction, delete the records, insert new records then commit?
